# Can't load Crystal Viewer with Asp Web Site

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

I can't load the crystal viewer for a **web site** that I didn't made but it works with a test **web app**

Same steps were done: 
- References added to crystal engine and shared 
- Web config objects added as it follows:

```
    <configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="businessObjects">
  <sectionGroup name="crystalReports">
    <section name="rptBuildProvider" type="CrystalDecisions.Shared.RptBuildProviderHandler, CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, Custom=null" />
    <section name="crystalReportViewer" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
  </sectionGroup>
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>
  <businessObjects>
    <crystalReports>
      <rptBuildProvider>
        <add embedRptInResource="true" />
      </rptBuildProvider>
    <crystalReportViewer>
      <add key="ResourceUri" value="/CrystalViewerFolder" />
    </crystalReportViewer>
    </crystalReports>
  </businessObjects>
<connectionStrings>
```

- Tried changing to 4.5 Framework (no client)
- I'm using visual studio 2015 professional
- Downloaded crystal reports 13.0.20

No errors displayed just the viewer doesn't load in the aspx page 
it doesn't recognize the ReportSourceID

**UPDATE**
I just made a new empty project and placed all the current files into it, now the crystal viewer works I have no idea why it didn't work with the previous project file but I'm gonna redeploy the website. hope this helps to anyone

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2**

It appears that crystal source cannot read files from the project if you add the source with the I/O it will appear like this *"Folder/Report.rpt*" and the viewer won't work. In crystal source you need to click examine and add the full physical path like this *"C://user/documents/VisualStudio/Projects/CrystalReport/Folder/Report.rpt"* like this the viewer will work